# In CGAL, face extended arrangement: vertex iterator returns some vertices more than once

Tags: cgal

In CGAL, I have a face extended arrangement.  When I loop over the vertices using Vertex_iterator, sometimes some vertices are returned more than once.  Is the Vertex_iterator guaranteed to return each vertex exactly once?

Comment: Each vertex should be traversed exactly once. Your arrangement is probably erroneous.

Comment: I found the bug in my code:  I was unintentionally changing the x and y values in a Point_2 instance.  CGAL considers them to be immutable.